# Error when creating new theme for magento 2.2

Tags: theme, magento2.2

Hi I am new to magento and designing a new theme, and taking the guidance from the magento 2 theme design.

I have installed the magento 2.2 on php 7.1 and everything works fine. Now I am trying to create a new custom theme, I created a directories I have created are

a) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/web/css/source

b) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/web/fonts

c) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/web/images/logo.svg

d) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/web/js

e) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/registration.php

**registration.php** code is

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,'frontend/designcafe/helloworld', __DIR__);
```

f) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/theme.xml

**theme.xml** code is

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework: Config/etc/theme.xsd"> <title>Hello World theme</title> <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- <media>
```

media/preview.jpg -->

f) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/Magento_Theme/web/images/logo.png

g) app/frontend/designcafe/helloworld/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

**default.xml** code is

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_c
onfigu ration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="logo">
<arguments>
<argument name="logo_file"
xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme/images/logo.png</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

When I load the admin http://localhost/domain/admin, I get an error

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning:
>   DOMDocument::loadXML(): attributes construct error in Entity, line: 1
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\dsgn\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Theme.php on
>   line 75

Please help me solve this

Answer (score 1):

Update your `theme.xml` as follows,

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Hello World theme</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media> 
</theme>
```

Clear cache